# Data loss in Arduino-Android usb communication

Tags: android, arduino, usb, arduino-ide, arduino-due

I'm transferring data from android to arduino and vice versa(handshaking is done). When I'm transferring one byte everything's fine, but when I try to transfer 64bytes packets there is data loss.

I checked the arduino side program and it works using Monitor of the Arduino IDE, but when it is connected to android it can not send packets of 64bytes to android(I have Arduino DUE).

I tried different baudrates and the problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks in advance.` ??? Please help yourself.

Comment: So a different problem. Why did you not tell earlier? Did you solve the delay problem?